# Type X is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-table

I'm trying to implement [this](https://www.bekk.christmas/post/2020/22/create-a-generic-table-with-react-and-typescript). I edited file structure to fit what I already had. Below is my issue:

[image]

I've looked at multiple posts but none worked. I can log out entries/keys/values to console using Object and it looks accurate, and typeof(row[column.key]) is string or number.

What do I do to fix this?

***Note***: after I Ctrl+C, the page displays correctly!

**UPDATE**:

```
├── @types/react-table@7.7.14 extraneous
├── react-table@7.8.0 extraneous
├── @testing-library/react@14.0.0
├── @types/react-dom@18.2.6
├── @types/react-table@7.7.14 extraneous
├── @types/react@18.2.13
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-router-dom@6.13.0
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react-table@7.8.0 extraneous
├── react@18.2.0
```

/src/types/types.tsx

```
export interface Cat {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
  color: string;
  activityLevel?: string; // optional, same as string | undefined
  favoriteFood?: string; // optional, same as string | undefined
}

export type ColumnDefinitionType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  key: K;
  header: string;
  width?: number;
}

export type TableProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
data: Array<T>;
columns: Array<ColumnDefinitionType<T, K>>;
}

export type TableRowsProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  data: Array<T>;
  columns: Array<ColumnDefinitionType<T, K>>;
}

export type TableHeaderProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  columns: Array<ColumnDefinitionType<T, K>>;
}
```

/src/components/Home.tsx

```
import { Cat, ColumnDefinitionType } from "../types/types";
import Table from "./Table/Table";
import { PageTitle } from "./Typography";

const data: Cat[] = [
  {
    name: "Mittens",
    color: "black",
    age: 2,
    gender: "female",
    activityLevel: "hight",
    favoriteFood: "milk",
  },
  {
    name: "Mons",
    color: "grey",
    age: 2,
    gender: "male",
    favoriteFood: "old socks",
    activityLevel: "medium",
  },
  {
    name: "Luna",
    color: "black",
    age: 2,
    gender: "female",
    activityLevel: "medium",
    favoriteFood: "fish",
  },
  {
    name: "Bella",
    color: "grey",
    age: 1,
    gender: "female",
    activityLevel: "high",
    favoriteFood: "mice",
  },
  {
    name: "Oliver",
    color: "orange",
    age: 1,
    gender: "male",
    activityLevel: "low",
    favoriteFood: "fish",
  },
];

const columns: ColumnDefinitionType<Cat, keyof Cat>[] = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    header: 'Name',
    width: 150
  },
  {
    key: 'age',
    header: 'Age',
  },
  {
    key: 'color',
    header: 'Color'
  }
]

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

/src/components/Table/TableRows.tsx

```
import { TableRowsProps } from "../../types/types";

const style = {
  border: '1px solid black'
}

const TableRows = <T, K extends keyof T>({ data, columns }: TableRowsProps<T, K>): JSX.Element => {
  const rows = data.map((row, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={`row-${index}`}>
        {columns.map((column, index2) => {
          return (
            <td key={`cell-${index2}`} style={style}>
              {row[column.key]}                  <-- *ERROR*
            </td>
          );
        }
        )}
      </tr>
    );
  });

  return (
    <tbody>
      {rows}
    </tbody>
  );
};

export default TableRows;
```

/src/components/Table/TableHeaders.tsx

```
import { TableHeaderProps } from "../../types/types";

const TableHeader = <T, K extends keyof T>({ columns }: TableHeaderProps<T, K>): JSX.Element => {
  const headers = columns.map((column, index) => {
    const style = {
      width: column.width ?? 100, // 100 is our default value if width is not defined
      borderBottom: '2px solid black'
    };

    return (
      <th
        key={`headCell-${index}`}
        style={style}
      >
        {column.header}
      </th>
    );
  });

  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>{headers}</tr>
    </thead>
  );
};

export default TableHeader;
```

/src/components/Table/Table.tsx

```
import { TableProps } from "../../types/types";
import TableHeader from "./TableHeaders";
import TableRows from "./TableRows";

const style = {
borderCollapse: 'collapse'
} as const

const Table = <T, K extends keyof T>({ data, columns }: TableProps<T, K>): JSX.Element => {
return (
  <table style={style}>
    <TableHeader columns={columns} />
    <TableRows
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
    />
  </table>
);
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: Try using `K extends Exclude<keyof T, symbol>` instead of just `K extends keyof T`. If does work for you I will write an answer explaining

Comment: You could convert `T[K]` to string with `{\`${row[column.key]}\`}`

Comment: @wonderflame - whether making that change in the file itself and/or in types.tsx, it causes additional errors

Comment: I will make an answer of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert `T[K]` to string with

```
{`${row[column.key]}`}
```